# jQuery, selecting an element by clicking on it

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to make an extension where it's possible to click on an element, and then for example remove it.
The idea is inspired by "Console" in "Inspect" in Chrome.

So, I click on an element (I think I should use `onClick()`), then pass it to an event where I can use the following jQuery code: `$('# or . elementName).hide()`

All info would be appreciated.

Comment: You should do exactly what you proposed. What's your question? Also, inside the click event, you can use `$(this).hide()`.

Comment: I have rolled the question back, since it was edited to something very different (and something that would be closed as "too broad") after an answer was given. @kazlaga if you have a new question, you need to ask it separately, not edit year-old questions with existing answers.

Answer (score 1):

**Note:** If you want to remove the element entirely, you should use `remove` instead of `hide`.

```js
$(document).on("click", function(e) {     // when clicking inside the document
  $(e.target).hide();                     // get the element that has been clicked (e.target) and hide it
});
```

```css
.item {
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: inline-block;
  min-width: 50px;
  min-height: 50px;
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.3);
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="item">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item">
  <div class="item">
    <div class="item"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```